# Windows 8.1 - "Chrome is out of date" Malware?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, malware, malware-removal

I've recently started getting a suspicious window appear in chrome which suggests chrome is out of date even though it isn't.

[image]

The window isn't part of chrome and can be closed using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f4</kbd>  when it has focus.

I've not found anything in the process explorer which relates to the window.

I've scanned with both Windows Defender and Malwarebytes. Neither found anything.

What is it? And how might I go about removing it?

```
Google Chrome   59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision    3cf8514bb1239453fd15ff1f7efee389ac9df8ba-refs/branch-heads/3071@{#820}
```

Comment: Have you tried an antivirus yet? Avira is free and will probably find a virus or malware if it is.

Comment: Yes. Neither Windows Defender nor Malwarebytes found anything.

Comment: Yes, I read it in your question. Those are not anti viruses per-se. I mean a proper anti virus.

Comment: You could try chrome clean up https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6086368?hl=en otherwise, look for ways to completely reset chrome to all defaults and remove all addins